# Jama and qasar in certain day

Tags: salat, salat-al-qasr

Salam,

I have problem that face me at my home sick. I have been worked at a certain distance from my home which allow me to held jama and qasar when it was.

But my mother said not to held it, cause it just ordinary travel which held once a week. I still held it cause I feel tired when I go home.

I still do it because, as my child, I remember that Anas bin Malik R.A. was held jama at somewhere in some years. I just not remember which / who say it.

Am I wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the hadith you are looking for is:

> ـ"وَحَدَّثَنَاهُ أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ، وَمُحَمَّدُ بْنُ
> بَشَّارٍ، كِلاَهُمَا عَنْ غُنْدَرٍ، - قَالَ أَبُو بَكْرٍ حَدَّثَنَا
> مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ جَعْفَرٍ، غُنْدَرٌ - عَنْ شُعْبَةَ، عَنْ يَحْيَى بْنِ
> يَزِيدَ الْهُنَائِيِّ، قَالَ سَأَلْتُ أَنَسَ بْنَ مَالِكٍ عَنْ قَصْرِ
> الصَّلاَةِ، فَقَالَ كَانَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم إِذَا
> خَرَجَ مَسِيرَةَ ثَلاَثَةِ أَمْيَالٍ أَوْ ثَلاَثَةِ فَرَاسِخَ -
> شُعْبَةُ الشَّاكُّ - صَلَّى رَكْعَتَيْنِ" ‏<sub>[[صحيح مسلم ٦٩١](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/14)]</sub>.‏
>
> I asked Anas b. Malik about shortening of prayer. He said: When the Messenger of' Allah (may peace be upon him) had covered a distance of three miles or three farsakh (Shu'ba, one of the narrators, had some doubt about it) he observed two rak'ahs. <sub>[[Sahih Muslim 691](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/14)]</sub>

Actually I don't know waht is the rule for your situation, but I quoted some of the questions that people asked Shayikh ***Mohammed bin Saleh bin Uthaymeen***

> Question1:Students go to study in a country, away from their own
> residents about ninety kilometers, by knowing that they go and return
> in the same day, Can they held jama and qasar?
>
> He replied by saying: I
> see that there is no held jama and qasar; because this is not
> traveling, as they have their breakfast in their homes, and have their
> lunch in their homes too. <sub>[[Reference for fatwa in **Arabic**](http://www.al-eman.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B9%20%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%89%20%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%84%20%D9%81%D8%B6%D9%8A%D9%84%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%AE%20%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF%20%D8%A8%D9%86%20%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%AB%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%86%20**/%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A8%20%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%86%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%AF%20%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%AF%20%D8%B9%D9%86%20%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%85%20%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%86%20%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%84%D9%88%20%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%8B%D8%8C%20%D9%88%D9%8A%D8%B0%D9%87%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%86%20%D9%88%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%B9%D9%88%D9%86%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D9%86%D9%81%D8%B3%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%85%D8%8C%20%D9%81%D9%87%D9%84%20%D9%84%D9%87%D9%85%20%D9%82%D8%B5%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9%D8%9F/i187&d95230&c&p1#Top)]</sub>

---

> Question2: I work as a truck driver and requires me traveling always,
> Can I held jama and qasar?
>
> He replied by saying: shortening the
> prayers related to travel so long, whether traveling rarely
> or always, and the driver of truck can held jama and qasar. <sub>[[Reference for fatwa in **Arabic**](http://www.ibnothaimeen.com/all/noor/article_2564.shtml) ]</sub>

And Allah knows best, Wa salla allah ala Mohammad.

Comment: thanks for the hadith, and I realized what traveling means to be.